# what is the mean of defining php file in javascript src property?

Tags: javascript, php

I found this script somewhere on a web page which has external php file linked in script tag. I googled it but nothing found useful. can anyone make me understand about this?

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="file.php"></script>
```

Below is the content of file.php

```
Bootstrapper._serverTime = '2015-08-01 11:50:50'; 
Bootstrapper._clientIP = '103.39.117.145'; 
Bootstrapper.callOnPageSpecificCompletion();
Bootstrapper.setPageSpecificDataDefinitionIds([])
```

Comment: As far as my guess go, file.php file contains only javascript. But its not wise to use like this.

Comment: This is standard and fine. Why shouldn't you be able to do that? PHP can output whatever type of content you want, not only html. Often it is used to output images or PDF documents, but also javascript or css is possible.

Comment: writing only nothing but javascript in a .php file and including it like above is not wise and proper.

Comment: @WilliamFrancisGomes That is not really true in a precise manner. It might be that you want to keep the _option_ of being able to do dynamic processing in the content.

Comment: @arkascha  in that case i may agree with you bro. But is it good practice?

Comment: @WilliamFrancisGomes Absolutely, yes. Creating content in a dynamic manner is what php is for. It is the same as with typical view templates used in a MVC setup: it might be that a template contains only html markup. But does that make the MVC setup a bad practice? No!

Comment: @arkascha bro my point was isn't it wise to use include() for a .php file rather then using <script></script> tag?

Comment: @AvnishAlok please update the question with what you got when you opened the file. If you are trying to include a PHP file that isn't generating JS though this is the wrong approach.

Comment: What @AvnishAlok means is: use the `edit` button below the question to add information to the question. Do _not_ post additional information as a comment yourself. That is impossible to read.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's not an unknown practice, many CMS's as well as projects use an "endpoint" or a "script" dedicated to handle the frontend resources.

They can perform tasks such as minification of resources into one single chunk, or just plain concatenation of resource files into one.

As long as anything (script or endpoint) outputs javascript, or in this case `echo`'s javascript, it can be used referred in a script tag.

> Note - This requires the script or endpoint to handle output headers as well, which is commonly done by sending in a `Content-Type` header along the response
>
> In PHP it's usually done using `header('Content-Type: application/javascript');`

Answer (score 0):

In my view in the given case `File.php` may simply generate `javascript` code dynamically (e.g. load some JS from database and so on).

Comment: Sorry you was a bit fajter ;)